# Upgrade to Laravel 5.1 - Method [validator] does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Last night, I upgraded my application from 5.0 to 5.1 .

Everything seems to be working fine, except the registration.

On entering the information, and registering, I get this error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 282:
Method [validator] does not exist.
```

Not able to figure out where do I have to fix this.

**RegistersUsers.php**

```
    namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use App\Services\Registrar;

    trait RegistersUsers
    {
        use RedirectsUsers;

    public function postRegister(Request $request)
        {
            $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                $this->throwValidationException(
                    $request, $validator
                );
            }

            Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));

            return redirect($this->redirectPath());
        }
}
```

**Controllers.php**

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        throw new BadMethodCallException("Method [$method] does not exist.");
    }
```

Comment: What is in line 282 in your Controller.php?

Comment: Then they changed the way how to call the validator. Normally you should find this things in the changeling

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you read the [upgrade docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.0)?

You need to take `validator()` and `create()` from `Services/Registrar.php` and place them into `Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php`. That's literally it.